Can this Free Logic prove everything ZFC can?
I would like to reason about undefinedness in a theorem prover so I was wondering if this Free Logic formalization will allow me to prove everything ZFC can? As I understand it Free Logic is a generalization of ZFC? I would like to do maths as close as possible to how mathematicians do things. https://www.isa-afp.org/entries/AxiomaticCategoryTheory.html

Your main question is a well defined mathematical question (up to the usual issues of what it means for two systems to “prove the same thing”, often translated as proving the same theorems of arithmetic).  But I don’t understand the part where you say you’d like to work in a theorem prover, but then ask about an obscure logic not practically implemented in a theorem prover (I think the document you linked to is some shallow embedding) and also suggest this logic is “as close to possible how mathematicians do things”.  Why not work in Isabelle/HOL, Lean, or Coq?

The way I understand it Isabelle/HOL, Lean and Coq have a different definition for division than mathematical division, they assign a value to division by zero, I'm not sure how to reason about undefinedness in these provers that's why I found an embedding of Free Logic in which I was planning to reason about undefinedness, maybe there's a better way I'm not sure

If you are worried about practice, then in practice the division of Lean, Coq, Isabelle/HOL is not a big issue.  There are also many ways to deal with partiality more directly.  You could define division to output an Option type which is none if the denominator is zero, or (in Lean or Coq) add the requirement that the denominator is nonzero to the function definition.  In practice these approaches can be annoying to work with, which is why division by zero is usually just set to 0.  But if free logic provides a better way to define partial functions, you are welcome to explore that.

As for your question at hand, isn’t Free Logic just a logic, like first order logic?  Is it even possible to use it to define numbers, sets, etc?  It would be like asking if FOL and ZFC could prove the same theorems?  It doesn’t really make sense as a question, right?

Free logic is a generalization of (classical) first-order logic. It basically allows for structures with empty domains, which does resemble what Mathematicians do in practice, but causes more problems than it solves.

Thank you, do you know where I can read more about the problems Free Logic causes?

Any book on Free logic discusses them (see, e.g., the references in the linked article). Things like $(\forall x\ldotp P[x])\implies(\exists x\ldotp P[x])$ fails (iirc). If you replace all instances of $\forall x\ldotp P[x]$ by $(\forall x\ldotp P[x])\land(\exists x\ldotp P[x])$, you avoid these problems...but introduce far more work for yourself.

Free logic is nowhere close to how mathematicians "do things", and neither is ZFC. Proof assistants are our best attempt to provide a rigorous environment that faithfully reflects how mathematicians do things. Encoding a logic, any kind of logic, in a proof assistant, and attempting to use the embedded logic as if it were the proof assistant itself, makes it harder to formalize mathematics, not easier (unless you're an expert programming Isabelle from scratch).
A detail such as implementation of division is insignificant when it comes to formalization of mathematics. The designers of Lean's mathlib did not just randomly decide to define $1/0 = 0$, and are clearly not obstructed by it. After all, mathlib is the largest every library of formalized mathematics, so they must be doing something right. I recommend at the very least studying how it is possible that they're so successful, before concluding that all existing proof assistants are wrong on the account of how they define division.
Having said that, I think that defining $1/0 = 0$ is an awful idea, forced upon mathematicians by a combination of things that I shall not try to enumerate here. It is quite easy to define division as a partial map that is undefined when the divisor is $0$, for instance in Lean the type of division would be something like
def div : ℝ → {x : ℝ | x ≠ 0} → ℝ := ...

However, if you do so, you will have to provide a proof of the divisor being non-zero every single time you divide. Some people don't want to do that, and I am one of them.

I don't understand what you are trying to say with your "rant" at the end. Do you think Lean's definition needs change? If not, why is it an awful idea?

Lean's definition is mathematically unacceptable. We teach 10 year old children that 1/0 is undefined, so how should I explain to my 14 year old son that I secretly use a tool that defined 1/0 = 1? It is a hack to work around the current limitations of proof assistants. The real solution is to have the cake and eat it to: make 1/0 undefined and make it easy to formalize proofs involving division.
